# Is custom exception is better to throw from java client?

Tags: java, spring, exception, client

I have a microservices architecutre and few microservices have its own client in order for other services to easily use the service API.

In case when we need to return response to some service from our client we also can expect that something wrong might happens while client request and client could return some http status (for example 404(not found) in case if data isn't exist for a such request or 500(internal server error) in case of unexpected service error).

My question is which approach we should use for throwing exception from client?
Do we need to create a custom exceptions on client side and handle these in appropriate way? For example MyServiceBasicException, MyServiceResourceNotFoundException, MyServiceInternalServiceErrorException and so on? 
Or we need to use already existing exceptions (for example from Spring *ResourceNotFoundException* that can be thrown in case if data isn't exist for a such request) or other libraries?
Which benefits have one and another approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to do some complex handling based on an exception type then you can extend one of the exceptions and do that. otherwise, if it's just for purposes of propagation i would say reuse.